# How can I format this number correctly using PHP?

Tags: php, numbers

I have a number with numbers after the decimal but for some reason when formatting it, the last two decimals are always zero.

For example a price is 154,95 as saved in my database, but I would like a number of 150 to be shown like 150,00. So I looked up number_format() and found this info:

```
number
The number being formatted.

decimals
Sets the number of decimal points.

dec_point
Sets the separator for the decimal point.

thousands_sep
Sets the thousands separator.
```

With above info I did this:

```
echo number_format($artikel['prijs'],2,",",".");
```

The comma should be the decimal seperator and the dot the thousands seperator. Still the result of 154,95 with above code is 154,00 , why?

I want all numbers to have the same format, a number with two decimals behind the comma wether these are zero or more.

Comment: You must start this process from a sensible mathematical number format i.e. `123.45`. So you should store the number in the database using an appropriate number format and then only in your presentation layer format them to be whatever format the locale requires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that first the price "154,95" is converted to number as 154, and after that number_format() starts to do his job.
Either you have to store in the database the price as 154.95, or you have to replace the character "," with "." before calling number_format().
Example:

```
<?php
$a = "159.95";
$b = "12345";
$a_number = str_replace(",", ".", $a);
$b_number = str_replace(",", ".", $b);

echo number_format($a_number,2,",","."), "\n";
echo number_format($b_number,2,",","."), "\n";
?>
```

And the output is:

159,95

12.345,00

Answer (score 1):

Change your enter number format.

```
<?php
echo number_format("1000000")."<br>";
echo number_format("1000000",2)."<br>";
echo number_format("1000000",2,",",".");
?>
```

Output:-

```
1,000,000
1,000,000.00
1.000.000,00
```

Answer (score 1):

This will round your number to the nearest multiple of 10:

```
$n = 123.45;

$multiple = 10;

$result = (ceil($n)%$multiple === 0) ? ceil($n) : round(($n+$multiple/2)/$multiple)*$multiple;

echo $result;
```

Then `number_format()` converts it to a string for display with the seperators (,.). In different locations they have the comma to seperate decimals and the stop to seperate thousands and vice versa in other locations so I usually leave those parameters out as they are optional anyway and I think it might change depending on the locale settings on the machine viewing it but I am not sure about that.

So I'd add:

```
$display_result = number_format($result,2);
```